# Не деплоится EJB на сервер GlassFish

Tags: java-ee, maven, ejb

Структура проекта такая:

```
-Project:
 --project-view:
   --pom.xml
   --webapp
     --WEB-INF
       --web.xml
  --project-logic:
    --pom.xml
  --project-model:
    --pom.xml
 --pom.xml
```

Вот основной pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
    <artifactId>DeepThought</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>DeepThought</name>

    <modules>
        <module>deepthought-logic</module>
        <module>deepthought-view</module>
        <module>deepthought-model</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compile.source>1.8</maven.compile.source>
        <maven.compile.target>1.8</maven.compile.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>DeepThought</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
        <artifactId>DeepThought</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
    <artifactId>deepthought-view</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>deepthought-view</name>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
            <artifactId>deepthought-logic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
            <artifactId>deepthought-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>deepthought-view</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

pom model:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
            <artifactId>DeepThought</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

        <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
        <artifactId>deepthought-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>deepthought-model</name>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.12</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>deepthought-model</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enhance</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

pom-logic:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
        <artifactId>DeepThought</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
    <artifactId>deepthought-logic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>deepthought-logic</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>deepthought-logic</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.projects.prog_ja</groupId>
            <artifactId>deepthought-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Работаю в intellij idea, в итоге всё собирается в один war архив view и деплоится на сервер(logic & model лежат в WEB-INF/lib) проблема заключается в том, что в logic есть 3 синглтона и 2 обычных stateless, контроллеры могут спокойно вызывать stateless bean с помощью аннотация `@EJB`, но когда я также пытаюсь вызвать @Singleton с помощью той же аннотации, то выдаёт ошибку, что bean не найден:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=ru.projects.prog_ja.Controllers.NavigationPanelController/facts,Local 3.x interface =ru.projects.prog_ja.ejb.applicationBeans.InterestingFacts,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
```

Вот такие аннотации над всеми Singleton:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@LocalBean
@Local(TagsSingletonLocal.class)
@Remote(TagsSingletonRemote.class)
public class TagsSingleton implements TagsSingletonLocal, TagsSingletonRemote{}
```

Вызов самого синглтона:

```
@EJB
private TagsSingleton tagsSingleton;
```

Пытался вызывать `@EJB` над локальными и удаленными интерфейсами, но все равно выдает NamingException, что не может найти

Не знаю, может я как-то не правильно собираю проект и эти бины не запускаются, было бы интересно почитать про то, как собираются проекты с несколькими модулями, заранее спасибо за любую помощь :)

Comment: Ви предлагаете угадать каким именно образом применяется аннотация @EJB к Вашим синглетонам?

Comment: @Sergey, я чуть чуть вас не понял, мне интересно почему есть Stateless бины работают, синглтоны нет, все ли правильно я деплою на сервер, мне казалось что при применении аннотации EJB и Localbean на синглтоне, контейнер сам должен предоставить доступ к нему, мб я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Можно нагуглить как это всё работает и сделать выводы что не так. Точно говорю, сам видел. Но в голове не держу весь этот бред, кроме простейшего случая, которого мне хватает. `@Inject TagsSingleton tagsSingleton` или `@EJB TagsSingleton tagsSingleton` и `@Singleton public class TagsSingleton {}`

Comment: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/introduction-to-ejb-30-injection-and.html

Comment: @Sergey, что интересно аннотация Inject работает, как бы только он каждый раз новый экземпляр не создавал

Comment: По спецификации Inject должен понимать с чем имеет дело. К тому же создаваться при Inject без аннотации класса аннотациями CDI не должно. Не знаю почему не срабатывает EJB. У меня работало и то и другое. Может домашний и удаленный интерфейсы вносят свои коррективы в EJB. В приведенном выше блоге вроде хорошо расписано.

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо вам огромное за помощь, но тут я долбоеб пздц я весь день мучался пытался сделать разные конфиги, все перепробовал, а проблема была в том ЧТО '@Singleton' была из javax.inject.Singleton, а не из javax.ejb.Singleton, прост капец, я хз че сказать